# Cannot download daily data with weathercan

Tags: download, weather

I am using weathercan package (https://github.com/ropensci/weathercan/issues)

With simple codes to download daily data from station 28011 (Regina RCS)
Then I got an error message:

Error in 1:grep("Date/Time", preamble$V1) : argument of length 0

Need help.

```r
library(weathercan)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

####################################################
#download data
#46367 = Hudson Bay
#####################################################################
stations_search("Regina RCS", interval="hour")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 14
#>   prov  station_name station_id climate_id WMO_id TC_id   lat   lon  elev
#>   <chr> <chr>             <int> <fct>       <int> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 SK    REGINA RCS        28011 4016699     71514 WDJ    50.4 -105.  577.
#> # ... with 5 more variables: tz <chr>, interval <chr>, start <int>,
#> #   end <int>, normals <lgl>
#stations_search("Kamloops", interval = "hour")
#kam <- weather_dl(station_ids = 10805, start = "2018-02-01", end = "2018-04-15")
Regina<- weather_dl(station_ids = 28011, start = "2019-02-01", interval = "day", quiet = TRUE)
#> Error in 1:grep("Date/Time", preamble$V1): argument of length 0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>